# Is there a fix for bootstrap utilities problem?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am using vue3 over vite and I am trying to implement the bootstrap to the project I was able to implement the whole thing but when I try overriding the variables related to the bootstrap I get a huge error can someone help me?

> Internal server error: [sass] $n: Invalid index 1 for a list with 0 elements.
> ╷
> 7 │   @if type-of($values) == "string" or type-of(nth($values, 1)) != "list" {
> │                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ╵
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_utilities.scss 7:47    generate-utility()
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\utilities_api.scss 13:9       @content
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\utilities_api.scss 5:3        @import
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 51:9            @import
> src\assets\style.scss 3:9                                                                                           root stylesheet
> Plugin: vite:css
> File: D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_utilities.scss:7:47
> Error: $n: Invalid index 1 for a list with 0 elements.
> ╷
> 7 │   @if type-of($values) == "string" or type-of(nth($values, 1)) != "list" {
> │                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ╵
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_utilities.scss 7:47
> generate-utility()
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\utilities_api.scss 13:9
> @content
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_breakpoints.scss 68:5
> media-breakpoint-up()
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\utilities_api.scss 5:3
> @import
> node_modules.pnpm\bootstrap@5.3.2_@popperjs+core@2.11.8\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 51:9
> @import
> src\assets\style.scss 3:9
> root stylesheet
> at Object.wrapException (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modul
> les.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:2107:43)
> at SassList0.sassIndexToListIndex$2 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_use
> er\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:115361:17)
> at _nth_closure0.call$1 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modul
> les.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:101930:37)
> at _EvaluateVisitor__runBuiltInCallable_closure9.call$0 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-0
> 001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:88716:35)
> at D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\n
> src\assets\style.scss 3:9                                                                                           root stylesheet
> at Object.wrapException (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:2107:43)
> at SassList0.sassIndexToListIndex$2 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:115361:17)
> at _nth_closure0.call$1 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:101930:37)
> at _EvaluateVisitor__runBuiltInCallable_closure9.call$0 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:88716:35)
> at D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:85689:29
> at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4887:15)
> at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:33983:12)
> at Object._asyncStartSync (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4851:20)
> at _EvaluateVisitor2._addExceptionSpanAsync$body$_EvaluateVisitor0 (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:85733:16)
> at _EvaluateVisitor2._async_evaluate0$_addExceptionSpanAsync$1$3$addStackFrame (D:\job\VAC Project shared with Weblink-20221101T145841Z-001\vac_dashboard_user\node_modules.pnpm\sass@1.69.7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:85670:19)

My SCSS code:

```css
@import "./scss/_variables.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "./fonts/Lato-font/latofonts";
@import "./scss/custom_styles.scss";
@import "./custom/css/dark.scss";
@import "./custom/css/components/datepicker.scss";
@import "./custom/css/components/timepicker.scss";
@import "./custom/css/components/daterangepicker.scss";
@import "./custom/css/components/bs-filestyle.css";
@import "./component";
```

This is my style.scss file no matter what I do it always give me the same error can someone help please?

Comment: Your issue is in your custom components somewhere. I used the exact same version of bootstrap, popper and dart-sass as you and have no issues importing.

Comment: I am not adding any custom components all I am doing is that I am overriding some variables and it refuses to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem it turned out that when I copied the variables file data from the bootstrap I copied the arrays without its data.

The arrays are:

```
$theme-colors:(
        "primary":    $primary,
        "secondary":  $secondary,
        "secondary2":  $secondary2,
        "success":    $success,
        "info":       $info,
        "warning":    $warning,
        "danger":     $danger,
        "light":      $light,
        "dark":       $dark
    ) !default;

$colors: (
        "blue":       $blue,
        "indigo":     $indigo,
        "purple":     $purple,
        "pink":       $pink,
        "red":        $red,
        "orange":     $orange,
        "yellow":     $yellow,
        "green":      $green,
        "teal":       $teal,
        "cyan":       $cyan,
        "black":      $black,
        "white":      $white,
        "gray":       $gray-600,
        "gray-dark":  $gray-800
) !default;

$grays: (
        "100": $gray-100,
        "200": $gray-200,
        "300": $gray-300,
        "400": $gray-400,
        "500": $gray-500,
        "600": $gray-600,
        "700": $gray-700,
        "800": $gray-800,
        "900": $gray-900
) !default;
```